# How to send WPS request using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, openlayers, geoserver

[image]I have installed WPS extension at GeoServer.I have generated the WPS request  using GeoServer's WPS Request Builder. For it I have chosen process=gs:Bounds, Process inputs=VECTOR_LAYER and chosen any one vector layer among I have uploaded then chosen option "Generate XML from process inputs/outputs' from WPS Request Builder. After it one XML file has been generated and i have saved i with .xml extension.
I have created one website using HTML,CSS ans Java Script.
Now I want to access this XML file from the website. How could i define that code?

Answer (score 3):

After you get the XML you just need to do a POST request with it. As an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WPS Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>How to send WPS request using HTML</h1>
<div><button onclick="getBounds()">Get Bounds</button></div>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
var getBounds = function () {
    var FEATURES_COLLECTION = '{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ] ] }';
    var GEOSERVER_URL = 'http://localhost/geoserver';
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    var raw = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
    <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"\
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"\
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"\
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"\
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"\
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"\
    xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"\
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"\
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0\ http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">\
    <ows:Identifier>gs:Bounds</ows:Identifier>\
        <wps:DataInputs>\
            <wps:Input>\
                <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>\
                <wps:Data>\
                    <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json">' +
                        '<![CDATA[' + FEATURES_COLLECTION + ']]>' +
                    '</wps:ComplexData>\
                </wps:Data>\
            </wps:Input>\
        </wps:DataInputs>\
        <wps:ResponseForm>\
            <wps:RawDataOutput>\
                <ows:Identifier>bounds</ows:Identifier>\
            </wps:RawDataOutput>\
        </wps:ResponseForm>\
    </wps:Execute>';
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    fetch(GEOSERVER_URL + "/wps", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
        console.log(result);
        })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
};
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Where:

- the variable raw is your XML in string format with the parameter FEATURES_COLLECTION, in this example I choose GeoJSON for the features format (at the moment of generating the XML), with OpenLayers you can use [writeFeatures](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html#writeFeatures) to get the value
- FEATURES_COLLECTION  is your features collection (ex. {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
  [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
  ]
  })
- GEOSERVER_URL is your map server url (ex. http://localhost:8080/geoserver)

Comment: i have updated the code by cabesuon's instruction.But it is not showing any thing. I was unable to add the updated code with this post. So I have added one snapshot of that code above. Please check and tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated the code, try just changing GEOSERVER_URL first, check it is working and then update with your features data. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i updated the geoserver URL by " fetch(http://localhost:8085/geoserver/web/ + "/wps", requestOptions)" this way. But it is showing a clickable button "Get Bound". When I am clicking it it is not showing any thing.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the url, try `fetch('http://localhost:8085/geoserver/wps')`. To check the errors just open the developer tool of your browser (before clicking the button) and see the result of the request (generated by the click) on console or network tab.

Comment: please check the bellow answer. i am facing with some errors. i have mentioned it bellow.

Comment: please the code once bellow. i have updated. but till it is showing same issue.

Comment: @florida add the code to the post please so I can check it

Comment: @ cabesuon  i have added the code. please check and tell me what the error is how should i solve it.another one thing is that i have added Geoserver link that one is on a IP.

Comment: remove the empty line after raw declaration

Comment: i have removed that empty line. but it is showing same errors on line no. 16 and 8.

Comment: i think we should define getbounds button [ line no. 8] to take the wps feature.

Comment: i have updated. but errors are same. check once the code please and let me know how could i solve those issue. it is important for me.

Comment: Ok, so you still have a problem with the string format, in this case is on line 37. You are missing the new line indication at the end of the line "\". Remember, this form of expressing a multi line string work like this, start with an opening character `'` or `"`, at the end of each line the character "\", and finally the end character (same as the start), and you can't have empty lines. BTW, I am gonna delete my las comment because it is bad formatted.

Comment: One las thing, check your polygon json format, I think you are missing the outer array `[]`. In polygons coordinates is an array of rings, rings is an array of ring, ring is an array of point, point is tow dimension array.

Comment: I understood your suggestion . thank you for helping me. I will update it. but I have a confusion that in your code how you have putted this coordinates value:[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]? that means are you getting these values from any feature?

Comment: I have putted the end of line "\" at line no. 37. it is providing following error:a.Access to fetch at 'http://13.233.108.174:8080/geoserver/wps' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.[ at line no 64].b.13.233.108.174:8080/geoserver/wps:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED.

Comment: You need to configure your server to accept cross origin request, there are several post about it. It is a Web security mechanism that is activate it when the domain use by the consumer differs from the server, just search for CORS and configure your server to accept.